# how can I convert string to an array with separator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsarray

I have a string in the following format

```
myString = "cat+dog+cow"
```

I need to store each string separated by + in to a array.
Eg:

```
myArray[0] = cat
myArray[1] = dog
myArray[2] = cow
```

Can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`componentsSeparatedByString:` splits the string and return the result in an array.

```
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];

[myArray objectAtIndex:0];//cat
[myArray objectAtIndex:1];//dog
[myArray objectAtIndex:2];//cow
```

Comment: @Sharman: Just for the sake of completeness: The inverse would be this: `NSString *myString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@"+"];`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
NSArray *arr = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

[arr objectAtIndex:0];//Hai
[arr objectAtIndex:1];//Welcome
```

Comment: without using array.because if i use array there is a chance to occur error

Comment: i have a message and accessmode

Comment: if you alloc and release array correctly,then no need to worry about that.

Comment: i will append access mode at first and then - and my message..i need to separate access mode and message.if i spitted like an array ther will be a problem if my message contains - character other than i appended

Comment: is the length of access mode constant

Comment: if yes,how can i retrieve first string without using array?

Comment: msg string retrieve the text after the first two characters and -(that's why i put the index:3)

Comment: Try this to get the first two characters...NSString *msg = [myString substringToIndex:1]

Comment: ok thanks..how can i retrieve first string without using array?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method of [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:).

```
 NSString string = @"hai-welcome";
 NSArray myArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

NSString* haiString = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* welcomeString = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: i will append access mode at first and then - and my message..i need to separate access mode and message.if i spitted like an array ther will be a problem if my message contains - character other than i appended –

Answer (score 1):

It is vert simple..

```
NSString * test = @"Hello-hi-splitting-for-test";
NSArray * stringArray = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

// Now stringArray will contain all splitted strings.. :)
```

Hope this helps...

I you don't want use array then iterate through each character...

```
NSMutableString * splittedString = nil;

for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++){

    unichar character = [test characterAtIndex:0];
    if (character=='-') {

        if (splittedString!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"String component %@",splittedString);
            [splittedString release];
            splittedString = nil;
        }

    } else {
        if (splittedString==nil) {
            splittedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];                
        }
        [splittedString appendFormat:@"%C",character];
    }

}

if (splittedString!=nil) {
    NSLog(@"String last component %@",splittedString);
    [splittedString release];
    splittedString = nil;
}
```

Thats all...

Comment: i will append access mode at first and then - and my message..i need to separate access mode and message.if i spitted like an array ther will be a problem if my message contains - character other than i appended – Sharmain 0 secs ago edit

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find this one very simple

```
NSString *str = @"cat+dog+cow";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
NSLog(@"Array items %@",arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

Array items
(
    Cat,
    dog,
    Cow
)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *strArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

firstString = [strArray objectAtIndex:0];//Hai
secondString = [strArray objectAtIndex:1];//Welcome
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *lines = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

The first value will be stored in 0th index of **lines** and second value will be stored in 1th index of **lines**..

Why not array?

Answer (score 0):

This will be the solution if you are dealing with a string:

```
NSString *mySstring = @"hai-welcome";
NSMutableArray *anArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[componentsSeparatedByString: @"-"]];
```

And each word will be stored in respective position from 0-n.

Try This. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are averse to using arrays, you can consider this –

```
NSString *accessMode, *message;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"hai-welcome"];
NSCharacterSet *hyphenSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"-"];

[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:hyphenSet intoString:&accessMode];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:hyphenSet intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@""] intoString:&message];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code :

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"cat+dog+cow"];
NSArray *resultArray = [tempString componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];

NSLog(@"1. %@ 2. %@ 3. %@",[resultArray objectAtIndex:0],[resultArray objectAtIndex:1],[resultArray objectAtIndex:2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSString *str = @"cat+dog+cow" ;
NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
NSLog(@"%@",array) ;
```