# How to split strings into substrings in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a string like this.

```
NSString *str=@"-85.33,45.78,0.0000 -85.78,46.98,0.000 -85.98,47.678,0.0000";
```

I have to extract individual strings from the above into an array.

The above string is 3 sets of longitude,latitude,altitude values. these are separated  by "," and spaces. I have to extract longitude values into an array and latitude to  another array.

Can anyone please suggest a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I convert string to an array with separator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111543/how-can-i-convert-string-to-an-array-with-separator)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method of `NSString`, or you could use the `NSScanner` class.  You could even use `componentsSeparatedByString:` to split on spaces, and then use `NSScanner` to parse the numbers out of each substring.

Answer (score -1):

Let me give you a hint. If you have a say a NSString, you can see what methods (with descriptions) are available by command-clicking on NSString in XCode. Then you would have seen componentsSeparatedByString:

The beautiful thing is this works for all objects. At least take a look before asking.

Comment: -1 for facetiousness. I wanted to do the same, and am quite accustomed to alt-clicking in XCode to see the class docs, yet still my first resort is always to SO for questions like this. Just goes to show the value of SO - it replaces basic documentation with mentoring. There's no need to RTFM when you can Ask TF Q (or search for it at least) on SO.