# How do I convert a string with comma seperated items to an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [how can I convert string to an array with separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111543/how-can-i-convert-string-to-an-array-with-separator)

Suppose:

```
string = @"Abc, Def, Ghi, Lmno";
```

I want those words, which are separated by comma, in an Array like this:

> element 0 = Abc,
>
> element 1 = Def,
>
> element 2 = Ghi,
>
> element 3 = Lmno.

Comment: u can search this link for more help                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111543/how-can-i-convert-string-to-an-array-with-separator

Comment: Please make use of the Stack Overflow SEARCH function before asking questions that have been asked many many times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

[myArray objectAtIndex:0];//Abc
[myArray objectAtIndex:1];//Def
[myArray objectAtIndex:2];//Ghi
[myArray objectAtIndex:3];//Lmno
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code out:

`NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourstring = @"Abc, Def, Ghi, Lmno";
NSArray *array = [yourstring componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Nslog (@"%@",array);
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like to use `componentsSeparatedByString`.
these kinds of methods are easily found in [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:)

Answer (score 0):

```
`NSString *str = @"This, is, test, string";
NSArray *myArray= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str ], nil];
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);`
```