# How do I convert comma separated string into integer array

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert a string of numeric values "20,30,40,42"; into {20,20,40,42} integer array in Objective C.

Comment: Possible duplicate (one of many): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111543/how-can-i-convert-string-to-an-array-with-separator

Comment: I would say with `componentsSeparatedByString` and `integerValue`. So far did you try to use them?

Comment: This is what programming is all about! Try something, post the code, you will get help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because some (coding or research) effort is required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
NSArray *numbers = ["20,30,40,42" componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

But in this case you will have NSString in numbers array.
You cannot store int into the array so your next step should be to enumerate that array and create NSNumber from string and put it to another array:
N

```
    NSMutableArray *numArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *s in arr)
    {
        NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[s intValue]];
        [numArray addObject:num];
    }

// Swift 4
let numbersStr = "20,30,40,42".components(separatedBy: ",")
let numbers = numbersStr.flatMap { Int($0) }
```

if you replace `flatMap` with `map` you get an optionals on Int instead of Int.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wanted an array of ints: `int numArray[]`?

Comment: @Zaph yes, you right but I believe he should tag this question in C language not Objective C.

Comment: how to implement this answer in swift 3?

Comment: @deltami Please see updated answer.

Comment: hey @Greg i have an array of selectedcells = [25, 19, 23, 18] using this array i want to enable the checkmark in tableview can you guide me how to do this?

Comment: This needs to be raise as another question on SO.

Comment: @Greg i raised a question can you guide me using code ASAP its very urgent. plz check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212064/how-to-set-enabled-checkimage-in-tableview-based-on-the-selected-cells-swift-3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","]`

Should work. :)

Comment: Try it, you will get a array of `NSString`s. That is not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have:

```
NSString *myString = @"20,30,40,42";
```

First separate the individual numeric string as follow:

```
NSArray *myNumberStringArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Then get the array of NSNumber  as follow:

```
NSMutableArray *myNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *nString in myNumberStringArray )
{
    [myNumberArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[nString  intValue]];
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: So close to another answer but missing the simplification: `[myNumberArray addObject:@([nString  intValue])];` And a closing `]`.