# How to set enabled checkimage in tableview based on the selected cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am fetching previously selected categorylist from the server. say for an example.cateogrylist i fetched from the server was in following formate

```
categoryid : 2,6,12,17
```

now what i need to do is want to enable checkmark in my tableview based on this categorylist,for that purpose i converted this list into an [Int] array like this :

```
func get_numbers(stringtext:String) -> [Int] {
    let StringRecordedArr = stringtext.components(separatedBy: ",")
    return StringRecordedArr.map { Int($0)!}
}
```

in viewDidLoad() :

```
  selectedCells = self.get_numbers(stringtext: UpdateMedicalReportDetailsViewController.catId)
  print(myselection)
```

while printing it's giving me results like this : **[12,17,6,8,10]**

i want to enable checkimage based on this array.I tried some code while printing its giving me the right result like whatever the categories i selected at the time of posting ,i am able to fetch it but failed to place back this selection in tableview.Requirement : while i open this page it should show me the selection based on the categorylist i fetched from the server.

```
var selectedCells : [Int] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell1  = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell") as! catcell

    cell1.mytext.text = categoriesName[indexPath.row] 
      if UpdateMedicalReportDetailsViewController.flag == 1
    {
          selectedCells = self.get_numbers(stringtext: UpdateMedicalReportDetailsViewController.catId)
        cell1.checkimage.image = another

        print(selectedCells)
    }
    else
    {

        selectedCells = []
        cell1.checkimage.image = myimage

    }
    return cell1

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = table.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! catcell
    cell.checkimage.image = myimage
    if cell.isSelected == true
    {
        self.selectedCells.append(indexPath.row)
        cell.checkimage.image = another
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = table.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! catcell
    if cell.isSelected == false
    {

        self.selectedCells.remove(at: self.selectedCells.index(of: indexPath.row)!)

        cell.checkimage.image = myimage

    }
}
```

output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common use case in most apps. I'm assuming you have an array of all categories, and then an array of selected categories. What you need to do is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, check to see if the current index path row's corresponding category in the "all categories" array is also present in the "selected categories" array. You can do this by comparing id's etc.

If you have a match, then you know that the cell needs to be selected/checked. A clean way to do this is give your cell subclass a custom load method and you can pass a flag for selected/checked.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell") as! catcell

let category = self.categories[indexPath.row] // Let's say category is a string "hello"
Bool selected = self.selectedCategories.contains(category)

cell.load(category, selected)

return cell

}
```

So with the code above, let's say that `categories` is just an array of category strings like `hello`, `world`, and `stackoverflow`. We check to see if the `selectedCategories` array contains the current cell/row's category word.

Let's say that the cell we're setting up has a category of `hello`, and `selectedCategories` does contain it. That means the `selected` bool gets set to true.

We then pass the `category` and `selected` values into the cell subclass' load method, and inside that load method you can set the cell's title text to the `category` and you can check if `selected` is true or false and if it's true you can display the checked box UI.

Comment: can you plz explain with a code coz i dont have an idea how to implement it.i'm really very newbie to this scenario.

Comment: Also one more thing to add this is a fundamental concept you will use in almost every app you could possibly want to build. If you go do some basic UITableView tutorials it won't be hard to find some that touch on this exact concept. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. hey but m not able to see the load method dont know why can you check my code and tell me how can i do the same in my case.

Comment: @deltami You can't see the load method because it doesn't exist by default. It is a custom method that you'll have to create yourself in your UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: say for example this is my selectedCells array : [19,23,16] m getting from server what are the steps i have to write in load method? can you plz edit your answer using my array? you can refer my cellforrow method have already added in my code.Please edit your answer if you can.