# How do I convert string of numbers to ints from 'complex' string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm familiar with the one-liner for converting a simple string to an int of course, namely:

```
NSString *aString = @"56";
int value = [aString intValue];
```

However, how would I go about extracting separate integers from the contents of a complex string containing various values, such as:

```
NSString *testString = @"26 8 102 65 53 2 190 784 212";
```

I've searched StackOverflow and other places without finding an answer to this specific problem. I had in mind something like:

```
int i, length;
NSString *testString = @"26 8 102 65 53 2 190 784 212";
length = [testString length];
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    // do magic here…
    // int value = 26 (the first number in string);
    // rinse and repeat until last number (212) converted to int…
    }
```

but I'm out of my depth here, and this pseudo code fails miserably of course. Can anyone help me with what SEEMED at first sight like a fairly easy problem please?

Comment: The string is not complex. It contains integers separated by spaces. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111543/how-can-i-convert-string-to-an-array-with-separator

Comment: As the comment above suggests, you just have to split your string first. You could even use a (super unsafe) one-liner if you like: `NSArray *values = [[testString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] valueForKey:@"intValue"]`

Comment: Or, if you don't need a `NSArray` of `NSString`/`NSNumber`, use `NSScanner`.

Comment: @vadian. I simply used the term 'complex string' to differentiate between the solitary string value contained in the first example. Sorry if this was the wrong term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like NSScanner:

```
NSString* testString = @"26 8 102 65 53 2 190 784 212";
NSScanner* scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString: testString];
while (![scan isAtEnd]) {
    [scan scanUpToCharactersFromSet:
        [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] intoString:nil];
    int i;
    [scan scanInt:&i];
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
}
```

Output:

```
2019-07-17 11:17:06.219506-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 26
2019-07-17 11:17:06.219639-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 8
2019-07-17 11:17:06.219743-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 102
2019-07-17 11:17:06.219885-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 65
2019-07-17 11:17:06.220024-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 53
2019-07-17 11:17:06.220150-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 2
2019-07-17 11:17:06.220286-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 190
2019-07-17 11:17:06.220413-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 784
2019-07-17 11:17:06.220518-0700 MyApp[1675:114852] 212
```

Collecting the ints is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for that! It works like a charm and is very close to what I asked for (without using an array which I didn't really need). Also gives me an insight into NSScanner which I hadn't used before.

Comment: `while ([scan scanInteger:&myInteger])` will work with this string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code snippet based on your previous code.

```
    NSString *testString = @"26 8 102 65 53 2 190 784 212";

    NSArray *testArray = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    for(NSString *numString in testArray)
    {
        int value = [numString intValue];

        NSLog(@"integer value: %i", value);
    }
```

Output

```
2019-07-17 10:58:45.460986-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 26
2019-07-17 10:58:45.461066-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 8
2019-07-17 10:58:45.461140-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 102
2019-07-17 10:58:45.461222-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 65
2019-07-17 10:58:45.461311-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 53
2019-07-17 10:58:45.461385-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 2
2019-07-17 10:58:45.461448-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 190
2019-07-17 10:58:45.461510-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 784
2019-07-17 10:58:45.461563-0700 ProxyTest[2337:109309] integer value: 212
```